# Sending Javascript variable to php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to send the value of a java script variable to another page and to store this value in a php variable on that page . Is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
JavaScript
==========
Var a="something";
window.location.href = "phppage.php?pass="+a;


PHP
===
$var=$_GET['pass'];
```